# How to manipulate the same element in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script on google sheets that calls an API and the response is an Array with multiple arrays, like this:

`[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]...etc]`

I'm trying to do something like trying to multiply the second element of each array by 2, **while keeing the other elements**. I have the whole array assigned to a variable but I can't figure out how to select the 2nd element of all arrays.

Comment: You don't need to select them all.  You just need to loop over the outer array and then change the `[1]`st element

Comment: Look at [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or see: [for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: `const yourArray = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]; for(let a of yourArray){ a[1] *= 2; }`. Of course, that will affect the original Arrays, so you might want to make a slice of the Arrays you don't want changed.

Comment: Could you not just multiply each array by another variable set to [1,2,1]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```js
 const arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
 const farr = arr.map(r=>[r[0],r[1]*2,r[2]]);
 console.log(farr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a few columns of values on a spreadsheet.  This function will put the same values right next to it with the second element in each row multiplied by two.

```
function multiply2ndElementOfEachRowBy2() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
  const arr=rg.getValues();
  arr.map(r=>{r[1]=r[1]*2;return r;}); 
  sh.getRange(1,sh.getLastColumn()+1,arr.length,arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```